# How to have an excel file save and update with the new information given

Tags: python, excel

I want to be able to update a status inside of a excel file using python it completes the process but, when I want to run it again it reverts back to the initial information given.

Is there a way to have the excel file be able to run and update with the new information each time the the program is ran.

Right now the program reverts back to the initial imported NewExcel.py dataframe format. All of the dates revert back to the original too.

When I append new data into the data frame it will save the new information but it will not when I want to update one cell at a time.

Here is the code I am working with any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import datetime
import NewExcel


#gets the dataframe from the NewExcel file.

Workbook_from_file = load_workbook("Canidate2.xlsx")

file = pd.ExcelFile("CanidateForm2.xlsx")

msg = ''
while msg != 'quit':
    Option_Chart = input ("Welcome! Which agency would you like to see?: \n1: View all canidates\n2: View a specific Canidate Form\nQuit\n")

    #Shows Every canidate as if it was in the excel file.
    test_number = int(Option_Chart)
    if test_number == 1:
        sheet = file.parse('Sheet1')
        print(sheet)
        continue

    elif test_number == 2:

        Option = input("Which sheet would you like to view? \n1: Sheet1 \n2: Sheet2 etc...")
        test = int(Option)
        if test == 1:

            sheet = file.parse('Sheet1')
            print (sheet)
            inputs = input ("Would you wish to \n1. Create a new Canidate\n2. View all statuses\n3.Change a canidates status\n4.Change the stage of a canidate\n")
            test_number3 = int(inputs)

            if test_number3 == 1:
                i = input ("How many peopole are already in the sheet?")
                num = int(i)
                num = num + 1

                Name = input("What is the canidates name?\n")

                JobPosition = input("What is their job position?\n")

                PhoneScreen = input("What date was the phone screen taken place?\n")

                Status = input("What status is the client on? either in process or closed\n")

                Rejected = input("Has the client been rejected?\n")

                Stage = input("What stage is the client on? \nClient interview \nPhone Screen \nOnsite Interview \nRejected\n")

                SalaryRange = input("What is the salary range the client desires?\n")

                ProvidedDocuments = input("What documentation has been provided?\n")

                Comments = input("Any comments?\n")

                LND = input("Last notification Date?\n")

                df2 = {'#': num, 'Canidate': Name, 'Job Position': JobPosition, 'Phone Screen': PhoneScreen, 'Status': Status, 'Rejected': Rejected, 'Stage': Stage, 'Salary Range': SalaryRange, 'Provided Documents': ProvidedDocuments, 'Comments': Comments, 'Last notification Date': LND}

                df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
                df.to_excel('CanidateForm2.xlsx')
                break

            elif test_number3 == 2:
                print (sheet.Name + " Status: " + sheet.Status)
                break

            #Changing a status from IN PROCESS to CLOSED and updates the last notification date
            elif test_number3 == 3:
                df = pd.concat([NewExcel.df], ignore_index=True)
                print (sheet.Name + " Status: " + sheet.Status)
                num = input("Which name do you want to change?(choose a number)\n")
                number = int(num)

                writer = pd.ExcelWriter('CanidateForm2.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
                #Need to load the workbook, or it overwrites all data on the sheet.
                writer.book = load_workbook('CanidateForm2.xlsx')
                #Evidently need to load the sheet names in order to write to an existing sheet
                writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets) 

                if number in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]:
                    nStatus = input("What is the new Status\n")
                    df.loc[df['#']==number, 'Status'] = nStatus
                    df.loc[df['#']==number, 'Status'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=None, startrow=number-1, startcol=8)
                    writer.save()

                    #updates the Last notification date when the status is updated as well to current date
                    nDate = datetime.datetime.now()
                    df.loc[df['#']==number, 'LastNotificationDate'] = nDate
                    df.loc[df['#']==number, 'LastNotificationDate'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=None, startrow=number-1, startcol=13)
                    writer.save()
                    print (sheet.Name + " Status: " + sheet.Status)
                    print (sheet.LastNotificationDate)
                    break
                else:
                    print("Wrong input please try again")
                    breakwriter.save()
        continue
    writer.save()
    continue
writer.save()
msg.lower = input("Would you wish to continue?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following?

wb = Workbook()
wb.save('balances.xlsx')

I see you are using save() but you don't have the workbook/sheet as a parameter.
See: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! When i tried using wb.save() it did not work. The excel sheet updates when the program is ran once. However, when i run it again it reverts back to its original format. I will rephrase my question to more reflect what I am asking.